# Kubectl command to check if cronjob is active or not

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm trying to check if a particular cronjob is active or not through a shell script to perform some action if the job is not active. I tried using field-selector attribute for cronjob and the job created by the cron job as below

```
kubectl get cronjobs --field-selector status.active==1
kubectl get jobs --field-selector status.succeeded==1
```

But getting these field selectors are not supported. Is there any other field/way where I can check if the cronjob is active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also set a label on your cronjob (and set the same label on the `template` part of the cronjob so it propagates to the underlying job that gets created), and then use that to select via:

`kubectl get cronjob -l label=value`

`kubectl get job -l label=value`

Yes, it doesn't select by active/disabled state, but you did mention in your question you were checking a particular cronjob, so this would bring up the details of the specific cronjob or job for you to check

To get the actual suspend state of the cronjob, you could pipe it to jq

`kubectl get cronjob cronjob-name | jq .items[0].spec.suspend`

This will give you "false" or "true" if the cronjob is suspended or not:

```
$ kubectl get cronjob -n test
NAME      SCHEDULE      SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
api       */5 * * * *   False     0        78s             5m53s
```

```
$ kubectl get cronjob -n test api -o json | jq .spec.suspend
false
```

You could probably also do this with `jsonpath`

```
kubectl get cronjob -n test api -o jsonpath="{.spec.suspend}"
```

From comment below, you use can `active` (i.e. currently running) , to see how many jobs are active (will be 0 if you don't have anything running)

`kubectl get cronjob -n test api -o jsonpath="{.spec.active}"`

Comment: I want to check if that particular cronjob is active or not to perform further action based on it. The script will already have the cronjob name so I can get that cronjob using the name itself.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include retrieving the suspend state out of the cronjob, would that be of use for you?

Comment: spec.suspend is returning false for both active and inactive cronjobs. | jq .status.active works well for me.. can you update this in ur answer